# windows service event log error Event 7011 not responded to

Tags: windows, service, event-log

I am getting this windows event on some machines that run this service but not all and during periods of no activity in terms of software usage.  My problem is I have no idea what in the C++ code for the service might not be correctly handled.  How can I relate event 7011 back into the C++ code...any ideas what this event actually means:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          2/6/2018 9:54:03 AM
Event ID:      7011
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      LEGNCOA02.calegis.net
Description:
A timeout (120000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction 
response from the App Server service.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-
26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
<EventID Qualifiers="49152">7011</EventID>
<Version>0</Version>
<Level>2</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Opcode>0</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-02-06T17:54:03.979566000Z" />
<EventRecordID>1654065</EventRecordID>
<Correlation />
<Execution ProcessID="660" ThreadID="186984" />
<Channel>System</Channel>
<Computer>LEGNCOA02.calegis.net</Computer>
<Security />
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="param1">120000</Data>
<Data Name="param2">App Server</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

The service does start and function correctly.  The timeout for these events was extended in the registry but that just increased the time between events by the amount of timeout increase.  In short it looks like windows is never getting what it expects.

Answer (score 1):

I worked this out...
Where the service handles SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP
also handle from winsvc.h
SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE
SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE
SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE
SERVICE_CONTROL_PARAMCHANGE
SERVICE_CONTROL_NETBINDADD
SERVICE_CONTROL_NETBINDREMOVE
SERVICE_CONTROL_NETBINDENABLE
SERVICE_CONTROL_NETBINDDISABLE
SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT
SERVICE_CONTROL_HARDWAREPROFILECHANGE
SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT
SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE
SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN

SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE was the one that windows was generating, no idea why it was doing that but responding as RUNNING seemed to handle it.